# Is this database scheme correct? (ERM)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design, entity-relationship

[image]I'm in the process of designing a small database for a project and I'm not quite sure if everything is correct with my design or if there is something that needs to be addressed.

It is about a management of events.

Especially with the table Participants I'm not quite sure, because there the user_id is contained and at the same time also with the Order. The table Participants makes sense for me but on the one hand because of the ratings that can be created only by participants and on the other hand for future extensions (chat, etc.).

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Hi. We'd need to know more about what you're modeling and what you intend to do with it. Perhaps ask just about the Participants table? Here's a few things. A Participant is a User at an Event, good, but it's strange they store the Order and not the Ticket. It's odd that an Order has many Participants and Order and Ticket are connected via the Participant. Perhaps a User has many Orders. An Order has many Tickets. Ticket belongs to Participant. OrderItem is then redundant, calculate quantity and price from an Order's Tickets. OrderItem has hard coded Ticket info anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to note that I currently have a 1:1 relationship between Order and Participant. That a ticket belongs to a participant makes sense, thanks already.

What I'm still wondering is how the scenario is handled when a user buys multiple tickets, since currently one ticket belongs to one participant (1:1). How do you mean that exactly with the OrderItem?

I have uploaded my updated version. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: 1) Because it references TicketCategory, OrderItem can only contain Tickets. Everything in OrderItem can be calculated from an Order's Tickets and their TicketCategories (TC). If you group by TC you can get a count of Tickets per TC for an Order, then sum(count * price) for each and sum those. And now the schema doesn't make Orders exclusive to Tickets. 2) The User makes the Order, but the Tickets in that Order can belong to Participants which can be different Users. 3) How are you handling discounts, promo codes, and coupons?

Comment: Ok thanks.

Would it also be valid for a participant to have multiple tickets (1:N), since in my case an Order can only contain tickets from one User? This way only one participant would be created for each completed order instead of the number of tickets.

I have not yet listed discount and promo codes in my schema. I think a 1:N connection would be good there, since a discount code can be used by multiple orders, but an order should only support one promo / discount code. What do you think?

Comment: 1) "*an Order can only contain tickets from one User*" When three people are going to an event together do they have to order separately? Assume that rule will change. 2) "*Would it also be valid for a participant to have multiple tickets (1:N)...?*" If a Participant is a User at an Event it doesn't make sense unless they can have multiple tickets for the same event, like carnival ride tickets.

Comment: 2 points out a problem: a Participant and their Ticket(s) can be for different Events. This suggests Participant is redundant. If instead Ticket belongs to User, you can get a User's Events through their Tickets and TicketCategories, and similarly an Event's Users through the Event's Tickets. Then a User can have many Tickets for the same Event, if that's how you want Tickets and Events to work. Participant might be repurposed to hang Event specific information for a User on. Though a key/value table would be more flexible with each row belonging to a User and Event.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. If I understand correctly, you think a good solution would be to link Ticket directly to the User Table and thus omit Participants altogether? This would make it relatively easy to handle that a user can have tickets for different events and also multiple for the same event. Instead of participant_id I would have the FK user_id on the ticket and a 1:N relationship between user and ticket. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up our comment thread into principles.

- Avoid having multiple paths to the same relationship.

For example, a Participant belongs to Event, but it also has many Tickets which belong to TicketCategories which can be for different Events.

- Avoid redundancies.

For example, everything in OrderItem can be derived from the Order's Tickets.

- Derive relationships through other relationships.

Users and Events are related through their Tickets and TicketCategories. Participant is redundant.

---

The schema would look something like this (["has many through"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) indicates a join).

- User

  - has many Tickets
  - has many TicketCategories through Tickets
  - has many Events through TicketCategories
  - has many Orders
- Event

  - has many TicketCategories
  - has many Tickets through TicketCategories
  - has many Users through Tickets
- Ticket

  - belongs to User
  - belongs to Order
  - belongs to TicketCategory
  - has one Event through TicketCategory
- TicketCategory

  - belongs to Event
  - has many Tickets
  - has many Users through Tickets
- Order

  - belongs to User
  - has many Payments
  - has many Tickets
- Payment

  - belongs to Order
  - has one User through Order

Participant which linked a User to an Event is gone. Now User and Event are linked by their Tickets through TicketCategory. If you want to have Event-specific User information, make a key/value table like so.

- EventUserInfo

  - key
  - value (ideally JSON to store whatever)
  - belongs to User
  - belongs to Event
  - unique(key, User, Event)

OrderItem is also gone. Everything in it can be derived from an Order's Tickets. Because it belongs to TicketCategory it meant only Tickets could ever be ordered. Without it other things can potentially be ordered.

You may in the future wish to add something like OrderItem back to record the specific details about ordering that item (discount codes, special instructions, quantity, the actual sale price) but in that case a Ticket would belong to an OrderItem instead of an Order.

- OrderItem

  - belongs to Order
  - has many Tickets
  - has one User through Order
  - price (the price at the time of sale)
  - discount code (specific to these items)
- Ticket

  - belongs to OrderItem
  - belongs to User
  - belongs to TicketCategory

OrderItem.price is a good example of when we do want redundant data. This is a snapshot of the price at the time the order was placed. For example, if TicketCategory.price changes you don't want the price on existing orders to change.

Then you can order other things by having them also belong to OrderItem.

Comment: I have now decided on the variant with the OrderItem table, since the prices of a TicketCategory can vary. How can I handle if an order is triggered, but the payment process fails, so the order is canceled. Currently, an OrderItem can have multiple tickets, but the available number of tickets is calculated by TicketCategory.max_quantity - TicketCategory.tickets.length. Would it make sense to deduct only the tickets that have a successful order associated with them via OrderItem? Or is there a "better" method?
I think deleting the tickets is not a good solution.

Comment: I have now created the relation between OrderItem and TicketCategory (1:N), as the ticket_category_id is also ordered for an order if the ticket purchase fails and OrderItem has no tickets. The relation between TicketCategory and ticket does not run directly, but via OrderItem. I would appreciate a short feedback if this is OK.

Comment: I see. Yes, separating the process of selling tickets from the process of determining if someone has a ticket sounds good; these are two distinct processes. Then one must ask; could you use an off the shelf shopping cart to handle buying the tickets? Then once the sale is complete it informs your ticketing system who bought what.

Comment: Would it also be an option to simply add ticket_category_id to the OrderItem in the solution you described earlier? This way, even if the tickets were not purchased or no relation exists, it would still be possible to track which categories were attempted to be purchased. The connection of ticket to TicketCategory would remain, since possibly in the future also tickets with e.g. seat number could be sold, which must also exist before a completed purchase.

Comment: Would this actually be correct from a database point of view, to generate / insert the tickets in advance (when creating the party), even if there is currently no seat number or so? What do you mean about the shopping cart exactly? Thanks for your time.

Comment: As you've identified, you can't count a ticket as sold, nor as someone holding a ticket, until the order is complete. You're doing two different things: sellling tickets to events, and determining who has tickets to events. If you build this as a monolith the ordering and holding can get tangled together. You can build this as two simpler pieces, one to sell tickets and one to manage ticket inventory and holders. One service handles the tickets, the other one sells them by talking to that service. The "selling" part could be off-the-shelf software. So could the ticketing.

Comment: I advise against adding ticket_category_id to OrderItem because then your schema can only support selling Tickets. OrderItem is an Item that is being Ordered. It isn't OrderTicket. What if you want to also sell t-shirts and other swag? How I've set it up you can add a Swag table which refers to OrderItem. Selling stuff is complicated, we haven't even gotten into taxes, fees, and currencies, which is why if this is production software I mention considering off-the-shelf software to handle the "shopping cart" side of things.